# Scraperwiki scrape query: using lxml to extract links

Tags: python-2.7, lxml, scraper, scraperwiki

I suspect this is a trivial query but hope someone can help me with a query I've got using lxml in a scraper I'm trying to build.

https://scraperwiki.com/scrapers/thisisscraper/

I'm working line-by-line through the tutorial 3 and have got so far with trying to extract the next page link. I can use cssselect to identify the link, but I can't work out how to isolate just the href attribute rather than the whole anchor tag.

Can anyone help?

```
def scrape_and_look_for_next_link(url):
    html = scraperwiki.scrape(url)
    print html
    root = lxml.html.fromstring(html) #turn the HTML into lxml object
    scrape_page(root)
    next_link = root.cssselect('ol.pagination li a')[-1]

    attribute = lxml.html.tostring(next_link)
    attribute = lxml.html.fromstring(attribute)

    #works up until this point
    attribute = attribute.xpath('/@href')
    attribute = lxml.etree.tostring(attribute)
    print attribute
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS selectors can select *elements that have an href attribute* with eg. `a[href]` but they can not extract the attribute value by themselves.

Once you have the element from cssselect, you can use `next_link.get('href')` to get the value of the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
link = link.attrib['href']
```

should work